# PHP - date() reduction bug?

Tags: php, date

I am using a unix time stamp as the base of my starting date for use in a date ranged query. The start date is not the problem, for the purpose of this example i will use the following time stamp: 1228089600 (01 December 2008 00:00:00).

For use in my query I needed to easily figure out the last day of any given month to the last second so..

```
date('o-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, date("m",1228089600)+1, 1, date("o",1228089600)));
```

This method has been working fine for me for every other month except December.. By taking the start date, adding a whole month (01 January 2009 00:00:00) then taking away 1 second I was expecting to result in the date I required (31 December 2008 23:59:59). However it appears the year is being calculated correctly for the additional month, but not for the subtracting second as the date returned is 31 December 2009 23:59:59.

As I say, this method has worked great until I discovered this problem. But it's a problem I am unable to figure out the cause of or simple solution to..

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because:

> flag 'o' - ISO-8601 year number. This has the
>   same value as Y, except that if the
>   ISO week number (W) belongs to the
>   previous or next year, that year is
>   used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

So in your case happens this:

1. Date generated is 1st January 2009
2. Date is decremented with 1 second (so you get 31st December 2008)
3. But as goes the description above - the week belongs to 2009 so 2009 is returned instead of 2008

(belongs to year means: More days of the week are in 2009 than in 2008 - in the case above: 3 days are in 2008 (mon, tue, wed - 29th,30th,31st) and 4 are in 2009 (thu, fri, sat, sun - 1st,2nd,3rd,4th))

Answer (score 1):

That does indeed seem to be a bug with how `mktime()` handles a "months" value greater than 12.

```
php > echo date('o-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, 2, 1, 2008));
2008-01-31 23:59:59
php > echo date('o-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, 3, 1, 2008));
2008-02-28 23:59:59
php > echo date('o-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2008));
2007-12-31 23:59:59

php > echo date('o-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, 13, 1, 2008));
2009-12-31 23:59:59
php > echo date('o-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, 13, 1, 2007));
2008-12-31 23:59:59
```

Your best bet right now is probably to just check the output from `date('m', ...)+1` yourself and special-case the calculation if the result is 13.

Answer (score 1):

I did add some exceptions to reduce the year if the month was January, however i also had another date range which is built at the same stage which is used with GA api. I was surprised to see this date range was fine despite the method being similar. The difference being..

Problematic:

```
date('o-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, date("m",1228089600)+1, 1, date("o",1228089600)));
```

Fine:

```
date('Y-m-d G:i:s',mktime(0, 0, -1, date("m",1228089600)+1, 1, date("Y",1228089600)));
```

So making the switch appears to have solved the problem.

Hopefully all this may be of use to someone, someday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$start = 1228089600;
$number_of_days_in_month = date('t', $time);
$end = strtotime('+' . $number_of_days_in_month . ' days', $start) - 1;
// subtract one second to get 23:59:59 or don't to get 00:00:00.
// Also note that there can be a leap second.
// $end = $start + $number_of_days_in_month * 86400 - 1; would probably work as well.

echo date('o-m-d G:i:s', $end);
```